# Getting Custom field values via API using chaining

Tags: civimember, custom-fields, api

I am trying to use the API to get membership data, including some custom fields.  I have the general idea, I think.  I can successfully retrieve the memberships, chained in the contact data, and now I need to include some data in custom fields.  The table the custom data is stored in is called "college_data_1" and one of the custom fields is called "enrollment_3".  So I believe I want entity 1 and field 3. I didn't find documentation that confirms how to find these IDs.  So what I current have in API explorer is:

rest.php?entity=Membership&action=get&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"membership_type_id":"Membership Name","api.Contact.get":{},"api.CustomValue.get":{"id":3,"entity_id":1}}

however this doesn't work.  Help?

I will need to include website data too, next.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to chain the calls, you simply need to specify the fields (return custom_xxx) you want to fetch from the membership.

On the API explorer, try to set the return fields you want, and check you can include the custom fields you want

Comment: It seems that I can only include custom fields for the main query... in this case membership.  I need custom fields from the chained Contact query.

Comment: That's a limitation of the api explorer, do use it to generate the code on the contact.get and re-use the return param when you call it chained from the membership and it will work